# Bootstrap Header's margin stops vertical centering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've made a [Bootply](http://bootply.com/104231) to demonstrate the issue.

When an `<h1>` is in a row with other content, it's margin stops that content from being centered vertically, even when using `vertical-align:middle;`. Is there another way to  get this content (the red buttons in the Bootply) to appear centered without manually copying the margin for it?

Comment: Do you mean vertically or horizontally centered?

Comment: Vertically (Its in the title, and the question). It looks broken when it's at the top of that "row" and the header is lower. I want it to be on the right, horizontally.

Comment: Ah.. now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put your buttons in the `<h1>` element, as :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1>
     Code
     <span class="pull-right">
       <button class="btn btn-danger">Small</button>
       <button class="btn btn-danger">Medium</button>
       <button class="btn btn-danger">Large</button>
     </span>
   </h1>  
 </div>
```

[**Forked Bootply**](http://bootply.com/104236)

EDIT : better to use `<span>` instead of `<div>`, to keep is valid.

Comment: Thank you. This is even avoids the nested row I was using, its perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same margins as the H1..

```
.center-y{
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

### Bootply: http://bootply.com/104237

Comment: I don't want to do this, I asked for a method without explicitly setting the margin. I don't like re-using bootstrap values, because if they update I will have to manually update mine as well.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I was just thinking this way was closer to what you already had.